# Transforming Raw Data to a Table for reporting Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

Bear with me as I'm self-learning.

Basically, I have this Raw Data where I got Date and SLT Percent which is a computation plus a state.

What I want is to group them Year-Month as Rows, Count how many Made and Missed are there for each month as columns and compute the mean/average of SLT Percent on the 3rd column.

I've been trying to do a grouper or groupby or unstack and doing mean also on groupby but I always got incorrect data. I can do this easily on excel pivot but I'm having hard time recreating it on Python Dataframe

Raw Data:

| ID | SLT Date | SLT Percent | SLT State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/28/2018 | 1 | Made |
| 2 | 11/13/2018 | 0 | Mised |
| 11 | 3/6/2019 | 0 | Missed |
| 12 | 5/20/2019 | 1 | Made |
| 13 | 10/25/2021 | 1 | Made |
| 14 | 11/12/2019 | 1 | Made |
| 18 | 6/4/2020 | 1 | Made |
| 19 | 6/11/2020 | 1 | Made |
| 20 | 8/6/2020 | 1 | Made |
| 21 | 12/9/2021 | 0 | Missed |
| 22 | 5/16/2022 | 1 | Made |
| 23 | 3/22/2018 | 0 | Missed |
| 24 | 3/20/2018 | 0 | Missed |
| 25 | 5/11/2018 | 1 | Made |
| 26 | 12/20/2018 | 0 | Missed |
| 27 | 5/12/2022 | 1 | Made |
| 28 | 10/7/2021 | 1 | Made |
| 29 | 3/21/2019 | 1 | Made |
| 30 | 4/24/2019 | 0 | Missed |

Output Table:

| Date | Made | Missed | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-5 | 10 | 2 | 80% |
| 2020-6 | 25 | 15 | 60% |
| 2020-7 | 50 | 23 | 23% |

[image]

Comment: please share the data as text/table in the question as oppose to images. Refer to guidelines here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Look at `pd.crosstab`

Comment: your output is not reflective of the data provided. There are NO missed in the table, but are in the summary. how?

Comment: also show your calculations of percent calculation

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is intentionally verbose for understandability.
Change column names & Percent formula (Made vs Missed) accordingly.

```html
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2013-01-01','2013-01-05','2014-06-01','2015-11-18','2015-12-21'],
                  'state':['Made','Missed','Missed','Made','Missed']}
                   )
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #Change date column format to datetime

df['Year_Month']= df['date'].dt.year.astype('str')+'_' +df['date'].dt.month.astype('str') # Creat Year_Month colum - for grouping

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'Year_Month', columns='state',values='state' , aggfunc='count').fillna(0).reset_index()  # Pivot table

df.rename_axis(None, axis=1, inplace=True) # remove index name

df[['Year','Month']] = df['Year_Month'].str.split('_', expand=True) #create Year & Month columns

df.drop('Year_Month', axis =1, inplace = True) # Drop uneccesary column

df['Percent'] = df['Made']/(df['Made'] + df['Missed']) # Calculate Made, Missed percentage


df[['Year','Month','Made','Missed','Percent']] # Print column in correct format
```

Output

[image]